# Use an object as a blueprint for other objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have created a simple object that want to use as a blueprint for other objects. But something is not going well. Can anyone find out why? When I click one button it should change innerHTML of the div to display the properties of the new objects!

here is a fiddle

```
var objekt = {
    name : "olsi",
    surname : "Angjellari",
    kot : function () {
        return this.name + this.surname
    },
    print : function () {
        id.innerHTML = this.kot()
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cTRuL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems:

When you want to do:

```
var dana = new objekt();
```

Then, `objekt` must be a function, not just an object because an object is not a constructor, only a function can be a constructor.  This is one way to do that:

```
function objekt() {
    this.name = "olsi";
    this.surname = "Angjellari";
};

objekt.prototype =  {
    kot : function () {
        return this.name + this.surname
    },
    print : function () {
        id.innerHTML = this.kot()
    }
};
```

---

Second, in your jsFiddle if you're going to put function names in the HTML, then those functions have to be global.  To make your code global in the jsFiddle, you have to set the upper left setting to "No wrap - in `<body>`" or "No wrap - in `<head>`".  As you had your jsFiddle, your code was defined inside an onload handler and therefore NOT reachable by function calls from your HTML.

---

Third, once you make `objekt` into a function to fix the previous issue, then you can't call `objekt.print()` directly.  You probably want to call `.print` on an actual object of type `objekt` like `dana` or `boi`.

You can see it all working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7TbEx/

Comment: I just pasted the code to fiddle, it didn't work on my computer either. But thanks for the insights about how to correct things when using fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you want to create a constructor so you can make instances using the new operator like you are trying

```
function objekt(name,surname){
   this.name = name||"olsi";
   this.surname = surname||"Angjellari";
   this.kot = function () {
      return this.name + this.surname
   };
   this.print = function () {
      id.innerHTML = this.kot()
   };
}

var obj = new objekt();
var obj2 = new objekt("First","Last");
obj.print();
obj2.print();
```

You could also make these through the prototype

```
function objekt(){}
objekt.prototype.name = "";
objekt.prototype.surname = "";
objekt.prototype.kot = function(){
   return this.name + this.surname;
};
objekt.prototype.kot = function(){
   id.innerHTML = this.kot();
};

var obj = new objekt();
obj.name = "First";
obj.surname = "Last";

var obj2 = new objekt();
obj2.name = "Last";
obj2.surname = "First";

obj.print();
obj2.print();
```